# regex with grouping

Tags: regex

I have to replace the following with regex.

```
echo Hello World $text
```

with

```
echo (Hello World $text)
```

My try is

```
(echo)(\w+|\W+)/$1($2)
```

But that is not yielding me the desired results any idea ?

Comment: [`(echo )(.*)` replace with `$1($2)`](https://regex101.com/r/mZDcM6/1)?

Comment: I give up, you're too quick, that's the second time today :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't your regex work? `(\w+|\W+)` is either going to match one or more word characters or one or more non-word characters, but not a combination thereof. This will, then, only match the space that follows `echo`, ignoring the rest of the line. Perhaps you mean to use `[\w\W]+` or `((?:\w|\W)+)`, but realistically, all you need is `.*`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mZDcM6/1/)

```
(echo )(.*)
```

- `(echo )` Capture this text literally
- `(.*)` Capture any character any number of times into capture group

Replacement `$1($2)`

Input `echo Hello World $text`

Output `echo (Hello World $text)`